PrimeReact Checkbox in Data Table doesn´t update the selected rows
I'm using Data Table from Prime React, the thing is that when I CheckAll and after that select a filter the selectedProducts doesnt update, they only do it when I unCheckAll and CheckAll again. Even though that when I export the CVS, it exports the rows that are filtered.
export default function DataTable() {

const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
return(

<div>
{setSelectedProducts.length !== 0 && (
<CButton
color="primary"
size="md"
onClick={() => setShowSendModal(true)}
Send{selectedRows.length} Offer
</CButton>
)}
</div>
<DataTable
onSelectionChange={(e) => {
if (Array.isArray(e.value)) {
setSelectedProducts(e.value);
}
}}>
..........
.......
......
<Column
selectionMode="multiple"
headerStyle={{ width: '3rem' }}
className="py-4 px-3 justify-content-center"
/>

);

I've tried to force the rerendering of the object, but I think the problem is that when filter is applied, selectedProducts is not setted. Maybe because it doesn't call the onChangeSelection.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
